# How can I send data to PHP script from SharedPreferences and display JSON in listview?

Tags: android

I want to display data from MySQL to listview.

Here is my PHP script:

home.php?s_id=

```
<?php                                            
$con= new mysqli("localhost","root","","studentbuzz");

$user_id = $_GET['s_id'];

$res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT class.c_id,class.c_name,class.c_desc FROM student_class INNER JOIN class ON class.c_id=student_class.c_id WHERE s_id='$user_id'");
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $response[] = array("c_id"=>$row[0],"c_name"=>$row[1],"c_desc"=>$row[2]);
}

echo json_encode(array("class"=>$response));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is my SharedPreferences data:

```
SharedPreferences ui = this.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo",     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String s_id = ui.getString("s_id","s_id");
```

JSON output:

```
{"class":[{"c_id":"12","c_name":"Java","c_desc":"Learn Java"}, {"c_id":"13","c_name":"ggg","c_desc":"ffff"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this to know how to send data from android to server
http://kb4dev.com/article/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql-and-json

and to send data from SharedPreference, use this

```
String s_id = ui.getString("s_id","s_id");
new SignupActivity(this).execute(s_id);
```

And for getting values from JSON, refer this

http://www.kaleidosblog.com/android-listview-load-data-from-json

If you still have any doubts, ask and I will help. Happy Coding!